# Adding to request parameters in a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

How can I add parameters to a link in a jsp without overwriting what is already there?

For example I have this now:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/Top.jsp?sortBy=downloads&sortOrder=desc'/>">
```

But if they have a search term in there (or whatever) already I don't want to lose the other parameters when I sort.  How do I go about that?  Do I have to use <% request.getUrl %> or something like that?

Comment: 1. Who is they? 2. Sort what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29).

```
<c:url value="/Top.jsp?sortBy=downloads&sortOrder=desc&${pageContext.request.queryString}" />
```

Comment: But what if I already had a sortBy parameter in my URL? How do I prevent parameters from getting duplicated?

Comment: @FelipeKunzler: `${empty param.sortBy ? 'sortBy=downloads&' : ''}`

Answer (score 1):

You may use array of query string params(must determinate all params manually, its OK if params not so much :) in jstl

```
<a href="<c:url value='/Top.jsp?sortBy=${param.sortBy}&sortOrder=${param.sortOrder}&nextParam=${param.nextParam}'/>">
```

In the case of using ${pageContext.request.queryString}, you may get duplicate params in query string